# how to install windows service using setup project in visual studio

Tags: windows, service

I want to install windows service with another desktop application using single setup.msi. is it possible

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible, in the Setup project, right click on the proj and select `Add/Project Ouput` select your Windows service project. Then go to the `Custom Action Editor`, for each action right click on it and select `Add Custom Action`, a pop-up will show up, select in there the Windows service output. Do this for all the custom actions and you'r done.

Comment: I have installed the service but its giving message that "Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger. A Windows service must be installed (using installutil.exe) and then started with the ServerExplorer, Windows Service Administrative tool or the NET start command".